# Social Sharing Phonegap Plugin - index.html not available (glitch)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Right now i'm using phonegap for my mobile app project. My problem is this glitch happen only on certain of device. I'm using social sharing phonegap plugin from here.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

I'm using iphone 5
[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in documentation of plugin you can see

> If Facebook, Twitter or WhatsApp is not available, the errorCallback
>   is called with the text 'not available'.

so there can be some error with privacy settings, or social account of selected network not configured on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the plugin behaviour in this exact case. Still, the errorcallback is invoked with 'not available' as Sergey mentioned correctly, but on iOS the plugin will now prompt the user to setup his Facebook/Twitter/.. account in the Settings of the phone (as per Apple design guidelines).

If you don't want the user to see the Facebook or Twitter button when he has not configured the app already, you can use the 'canShareVia' methods check beforehand.

Hope this helps,
Eddy